# Why can't horcruxes in Harry Potter be destroyed by Avada Kedavra?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux, avada-kedavra

In the **Deathly Hallows** book/movie, Voldemort 'kills' Harry with the avada kedavra curse. But if Harry was a **Horcrux**, then why can't the other horcruxes be destroyed by Avada Kedavra? It might be because they're not alive, but then **why didn't Harry die with the Horcrux?**

Comment: Harry wasn't a Horcrux.

Comment: @MattGutting  Harry was an 'unofficial' horcrux.

Comment: There either is or ain't is a Horcrux ;) Aside from what J.K. Rowling says, canonically, Harry cannot be a Horcrux -- he did not complete all the steps to becoming a Horcrux. There can't be a Horcrux without the Horcrux spell, which Harry was never subjected to. :)

Comment: And yet in book 7 Dumbledore literally says he was the 7th horcrux.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo I'm pretty sure Rowling said that she had him say that out of convenience. I'm pretty sure even that it's in the same quote where she says Harry wasn't a Horcrux proper. But maybe the latter is incorrect.